# Como ativar o modal através da opção em um select?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, html-select, modal

Exemplo: Quando eu selecionar a opção "volvo", o modal aparecer...

```html
<label>Recinto</label>
<select class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cria-recinto">
   <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cria-recinto">O meu coliseu</option>
   <option>volvo</option>
   <option>A minha arena</option>
   <option>a garagem da minha vizinha</option>
   <option>Na esquina</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('select').change(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == "volvo") {
         $('#cria-recinto').modal('show');
      }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa colocar um `value` nas `options`, e criar a `div` com o `modal`. No exemplo abaixo usei o [modal da documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples) adaptado ao seu código (veja abaixo clicando em "Executar trecho de código").

```js
   $('select').on('change', function () {
   if ($(this).val() == "volvo") {
   $('#cria-recinto').modal('show');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label>Recinto</label>
   <select class="form-control" data-toggle="modal">
      <option value ="coliseu">O meu coliseu</option>
      <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
      <option value="minhaarena">A minha arena</option>
      <option value="garagem">a garagem da minha vizinha</option>
      <option value="esquina">Na esquina</option>
   </select>

    
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cria-recinto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! O problema é que eu quero que o modal só venha aparecer somente depois de eu ter selecionado o opção "volvo", entendeu? Esse exemplo que você fez o modal já aparece quando clica nos selects (sem ter escolhido uma opção). Você poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, Renan. Funcionou perfeitamente da forma que eu queria :)

Comment: Valeu @renan! Editei a resposta. Eu tava aqui tentando resolver isso, e já tinha tentando as duas coisas, mas separadamente. :-)

Comment: Nem precisava, tranquilo! Valeu mesmo! O importante é aprender! Mas depois apago os meus tbm, pra não ficar sem sentido! Valeu! @renan

Comment: É isso aí! Obrigado gente. Até as próximas ;)